# Compile TypeScript without keeping directory structure

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

My `./src` folder is organized in directories and sub-directories with `.ts` files.

When I compile using `outDir: "dist"`, the structure of the directory is the same as `src` with `.js` files.

Since my application is a CLI that will be deployed on NPM, I don't want the `dist` to look like `src`.

I tried to use `outFile` with modules `amd` or `system` but the program does not work anymore at runtime. Because, obviously, I have respectively `defined` and `System` not found errors.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do ?

(I also tried Webpack, but no success with the system imports)

Comment: Why do you want that? the CLI should use the `bin` field in `package.json`. In general the consumer should not care about your folder structure.

Comment: Actually, we don't necessarily want the code to be "easily" readable.